# Kusto - Join two tables and count keys from first table and second table on every record from first table

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, summarize, kusto-explorer

Need to Join two tables and count key from first table and second table on every record from first table

```
let T = datatable(TId:int, TName:string, Tkey:string)
[
   1, "A", "xyz",
   2, "B", "xyz",
   3, "C", "yza",
];
let u = datatable(UId:int, UName:string, Ukey:string)
[
   1, "bla1", "xyz",
   2, "bla2", "xyz",
   30, "bla3", "xyz",
   12, "bla5", "xyz",
   80, "bla9", "xyz",
   4, "bla11", "cde",
   55, "bla12", "yza",
   96, "bla21", "yza",
];

Expected result
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let T = datatable(TId:int, TName:string, Tkey:string)
[
   1, "A", "xyz",
   2, "B", "xyz",
   3, "C", "yza",
];
let u = datatable(UId:int, UName:string, Ukey:string)
[
   1, "bla1", "xyz",
   2, "bla2", "xyz",
   30, "bla3", "xyz",
   12, "bla5", "xyz",
   80, "bla9", "xyz",
   4, "bla11", "cde",
   55, "bla12", "yza",
   96, "bla21", "yza",
];
let T_sum = T | summarize TkeyCount = count() by Tkey;
let u_sum = u | summarize UkeyCount = count() by Ukey;
T
| extend Ukey = Tkey
| lookup kind=leftouter T_sum on Tkey
| lookup kind=leftouter u_sum on Ukey
```

| TId | TName | Tkey | Ukey | TkeyCount | UkeyCount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | xyz | xyz | 2 | 5 |
| 2 | B | xyz | xyz | 2 | 5 |
| 3 | C | yza | yza | 1 | 2 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA4WQQWvDIBSA74H8h0dOLeSwpMtYO3rYetplJz2NMUx9GyHGjFShCf3xe1oDc2sZgvo%203/PzqdAAgy1IYWjUChfsWW4abXJgL6LDzcEMjf6kqMUxBMs0eU0TAChyyB4zmo7jlOUelRQ9xWhF0c6hcRIOvT2kiSKtjbR81vJIy69oayWKv2ai5S/5zRmvYlyE7CrG9yF7HePbIPTGvcSAqyrw8kd3xNd34SnFha7Z%208F21DmDE9CuE0Mzof/dXW%201oZO9WxdLqEeP598KdTaq45fr%20LmOpckJ8GhQS4%20clhZHVd%2039gvaRsutwg/TW4NDeFyv/0mzc5q79BtGSClnQgIAAA==)